# Atualizar uma página depois de submit PHP

Tags: php

Quero atualizar a minha página (refresh), depois de clicar num botão que está numa popup. Este é o formulário da página popup.

```
<form method="POST" action="_cal.php" >
        <input type=submit value=Fechar onclick=window.close()>
</form>
```

Quando clicar no fechar da popup, quero atualizar a minha página "_cal.php".

Comment: Essa popup é aberta pela página _cal.php ?

Comment: Não, é aberta por outa popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na popup, indique no evento `onunload` (que vai ser acionado quando você mandar fechar a popup) para a página pai ser recarregada.

```
<body onunload="window.opener.location.reload()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma alternativa adaptada de uma [resposta do SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5712425/916193):

Esse código é uma alternativa interessante caso se prefira que o controle fique por conta da janela que abre o *popup*, e não dentro do *popup* propriamente dito.

```
function pop() {
  var child = window.open('http://ddg.gg', '','toolbar=0,status=0,width=400,height=200');
  var timer = setInterval( CheckChild, 500 );

  function CheckChild() {
    if (child.closed) {
      alert("Aqui voce recarrega a pagina");
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/j9sx4y4a/)**.

Basta trocar a linha do `alert` pelo `window.location` desejado.